# Fetching a list of projects for a user in Azure DevOps

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to fetch the list of projects for a specific user.Upon my research I have found 2 ways of doing this

1. Using the OAuth Mechanism and then using the token to fetch a list of projects that an authenticated user is part of.([https://dev.azure.com/{Organization_Name}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7BOrganization_Name%7D/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1)) and it works fine but the problem is with my use case that I want to show the list of projects in a drop down and when ever I follow this approach I will have to authorize myself on the authorization screen.So is there a way to by pass that ?
2. I have also found a way by which we can create PATs (Personal access tokens) and then call the Azure DevOps APIs but I haven't been able to find an endpoint that can return list of projects for a "Speciifc" user, so does anyone have any Idea how this can be achieved ?
3. My last question is since the authentication in my application is backed by Azure AD can I use the AD token on Azure DevOps APIs ?

Just to give you an idea I am developing a .Net Core 3.1 web application backed by Azure AD Authentication and for a specific functionality I need to fetch the list of projects from Azure DevOps that the signed user is a part of.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: yes Thank you @LeoLiu-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fetching a list of projects for a user in Azure DevOps

You could achieve this with PATs (Personal access tokens) and then call the Azure DevOps API [User Entitlements - Get User Entitlement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements/{userId}?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

To get the `userId` by the REST API [User Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

With this REST API, we could get the `userId`.

The test powershell scripts:

```
$connectionToken="<MyPAT>"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$ProjectsBelongUrl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/<MyOrganization>/_apis/userentitlements/<userId>?api-version=5.1-preview.2" 

Write-Host "URL: $ProjectsBelongUrl"

$UserEntitlements = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ProjectsBelongUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

$ProjectsList = $($Pipelines.projectEntitlements.projectRef.name | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)


Write-Host "User XX belog to which projects = $ProjectsList"
```

The test result:

[image]